# In AWS SFN does Pass state also affect execution cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, cost-management

As I know SFN standard version is taxed by the number of state transitions. Since "Pass" state looks very simple and lightweight (Mostly used for transformation of the request), I'm wondering if it still causes the state transition or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it applies to all state transitions. It doesn't matter whether it's lightweight or not, since you are charged for compute separately (a Lambda step incurs regular Lambda charges)